Getting data from varying places in XML with no or changing schema?
I can't figure out how to solve this problem conceptually.  I will receive many invoices in XML format.  Reading this format and saving data is not a problem.
The problem is that the tags in which the data I need are often have different names. Here is an example:
<invoice>
 <IssueDate>2024-07-15</px:IssueDate>
<invoice>

and
<invoice>
   <LZR_Beginn>16.07.2024</LZR_Beginn>
<invoice>

Initially I wrote
if not...."necessary" tag, then look in "another" tag,
but over time there were too many of them.  Besides, there are often new tags that were not there before and the data is not read.
I also tried to count how many tags I use are in HTML and created several templates, but in this case there is the same number of necessary tags or again tags that did not exist yet.
My question is, is there any possibility/ideas on how to solve this issue? Is it possible to "teach" the program to save new tags and add them to the necessary templates? Or create one main template and add all tags to it? Maybe you have experience with such solutions?

No, there's no reliable generic way for a program to know that LZR_Beginn in %d.%m.%y format is equivalent to IssueDate in %Y-%m-%d format.

I agree with the answer from @kjhughes. If your date is always inside the invoice tag and this is the only one you can try to check, if there is a date found:
from datetime import datetime
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_ ="""<root>
<invoice>
 <IssueDate>2024-07-15</IssueDate>
</invoice>
<invoice>
   <LZR_Beginn>16.07.2024</LZR_Beginn>
</invoice>
</root>"""

def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d/%m/%Y'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found')

root = ET.fromstring(xml_)

for elem in root.findall(".//invoice/*"):
    print(try_parsing_date(elem.text))

Output:
2024-07-15 00:00:00
2024-07-16 00:00:00


I assume that  <IssueDate>2024-07-15</px:IssueDate> is a typo limited to your question, not your actual XML.  If it's your actual XML, see How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?
Regarding your code getting complicated due to having to check multiple places for data, including the possibility of new tags being introduced unexpectedly:

Slop in tag semantics translates to slop in code.  There's no getting around such coding troubles without eliminating the slop in tag semantics.
XML and schema versioning become more complicated at the programming level the less discipline is adopted at the data level.

Fix your data discipline or suffer from the resulting complexity and associated risk.
